# Why creation date for PostgreSQL tables is null?

Tags: postgresql, date

I am trying to find out the date that each table was created in the database. I used the following code:

```
SELECT relfilenode, 
relname, (pg_stat_file('./base/24576' || '/' || relfilenode::text)).*
FROM pg_class 
WHERE relkind LIKE 'r'
AND relfilenode <> 0
order by modification ASC;
```

The result has null for the creation date of all tables:

[image]

How can I have the correct creation date for the tables??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [per the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html), the `creation` date column only applies to Windows platforms.

Besides, that's not a very reliable way to get the creation date of a table.  When you perform a `VACUUM FULL` on a table, the relfilenode will change (as well as a few other maintenance commands)--when that happens, you would be led to think that the "creation date" was "just now."  If you want to track schema changes, you should [implement event triggers](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-use-event-triggers-postgresql).

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com).

Comment: yes, I am using linux thats why the creation date is null.

Comment: @richyen Thanks for the link to the sample code. I found it very useful. The second trigger has a bug though I think, it should be   IF tg_tag = 'DROP TABLE'

  THEN

    FOR r IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_dropped_objects()

Comment: @Dowlers, thanks for bringing that to my attention--I'm having that fixed ASAP